# Can I solve the ODE $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2+1}{2xy+1}$ with a change of variable?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

[image]

In their answer explanation, they seem to have found the solution for x(y) rather than y(x). Is this allowed? I.e., are they even referring to the same solution curves? What I did instead was the following change of variable.

---

Let $v(x)=2xy$ (suggested by the "shape" of the ODE). Then $$y=\frac{v}{2x}\implies y'=\frac{2xv'-2v}{4x^2}\implies xv'-v=\frac{v^2}{v+1}\text{ from substituting back into the original ODE.}$$

Then $xv'=\frac{v^2}{v+1}+v=\frac{v^2+v^2+v}{v+1}=\frac{2v^2+v}{v+1} \implies \int \frac{v+1}{2v^2+v}dv=\int \frac 1x dx.$

\begin{align*}\text{LHS: } \int \frac{v}{2v^2+v} + \int \frac 1{2v^2+v},\\
\text{Then using partial fractions on the second term: } \frac Av + \frac{B}{2v+1} \\
&\implies A(2v+1)+Bv=1 \implies \int \frac 1v -2\int \frac 1{2v+1} \\
&= \ln |v| -2\ln |2v+1| \\ 
\text{So the entire expression overall is: } \ln |2v+1|+\ln |v| -2\ln |2v+1| \\
&= \ln |x| + c \\ 
&\implies \ln \left | \frac{(2v+1)v}{(2v+1)^2} \right | = \ln |x| +c \\ 
&\implies [\text{exponentiate both sides}] \implies \frac v{2v+1}=Ax \\ 
&\implies [\text{change back to original variables x & y }] \\
&\implies \frac{2xy}{4xy+1}=Ax \\
&\implies y=\frac{Ax}{2x-4Ax^2} = \frac{A}{2-4Ax}\quad\square\end{align*}

where C,A are constants of integration.

Could someone please confirm whether or not my method/working is valid? If not, could someone please comment on where/why it went wrong or does not work?

Comment: You made a mistake that compromises your solution: $$xv'-v=2x^2y'=2x^2\left(\frac{y^2+1}{2xy+1}\right)=2x^2\left(\frac{\frac{v^2}{4x^2}+1}{v+1}\right)=\frac{\frac{v^2}{2}+2x^2}{v+1}\neq\frac{v^2}{v+1}.$$

Comment: The easiest way to check if your solution is correct would be to plug it into the original equation. But doing so leads to one that doesn't always hold.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question posed in the middle of your post:

> In their answer explanation, they seem to have found the solution for x(y) rather than y(x). Is this allowed? I.e., are they even referring to the same solution curves?

The answer is yes, this is allowed. Per the [implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), under a few simple assumptions, any equation that defines $x$ as a function of $y$ equivalently defines $y$ as a function of $x$ in some interval.

If you play around with the equation in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/omsqaw87al), you'll see that for some values of $C$ (e.g. 0) you get something that looks like a perfectly good function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$, whereas for others (e.g. 2) you have a curve that turns back on itself, so you have two potential functions for $y$ that meet at some point. This is similar to how the relation $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ can be seen as describing two functions for $y(x)$, one being $y = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ and the other $y = -\sqrt{1 - x^2}$.